# Can I test my iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 apps on an iPad mini retina

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm new to the iOS world. I'm developing iOS apps but I have no device for testing, so finally I have decided to buy a device, but I'm confused which device to buy.

I want to test my app for both iPhone and iPad, so I decided to purchase iPad mini with retina.

Can I test my iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 retina apps and graphics on the iPad mini with retina?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run iPhone apps on a retina iPad mini but you cannot test anything that may rely on the hardware features that exist in the iPhone but not the iPad - namely the GPS. If you buy an iPad Mini with Cellular, I think you'd be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get everything done with that set-up indeed, except GPS and phone calls which are blocked on an iPad. (You're able to throw a message when this happens, please check StackOverflow for this, if you want it)

If you create iPhone only apps, they will display on iPhone size, and if you create an iPad or even universal app it will display full screen on your iPad.

**You can always start with the simulator provided by X-Code first.**

Good luck developing!